# adicionar botao customizado coluna do datatables

Tags: php, jquery-datatables

Estou tentando adicionar um botão com o `id` do usuário ao datatables com serverside fiz várias tentativas sem sucesso, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.
Esse é o meu código datatables:

```
    $('#jsontable').dataTable({
"oLanguage": {
  "sUrl": "busca/pt-br.txt"
},
        "responsive": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "busca/busca_usuario.php"
});
```

Esse é o array do busca_usuario:

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => '`a`.`nome`',         'dt' => 0, 'field' => 'nome' ),
    array( 'db' => '`a`.`cpf`',          'dt' => 1, 'field' => 'cpf' ),
    array( 'db' => '`a`.`situacao`',     'dt' => 4, 'field' => 'situacao'),
    array( 'db' => '`b`.`descricao`',    'dt' => 2, 'field' => 'descricao' ),
    array( 'db' => '`c`.`descricao`',    'dt' => 3, 'field' => 'nomegh', 'as' => 'nomegh' ),

);
```

Os dados chegam assim:

```
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":28,"recordsFiltered":28,"data":[{"0":"ADRIANO TESTE","1":"0000000000","4"
:"ativo","2":"Aluno","3":"Aluno 1ª série"}]}
```

Consegui adicionar o link a coluna só falta conseguir pegar o id do usuário:

deixo minha tentativa para ajudar outros com a mesma dúvida:

```
    $('#jsontable').dataTable({
"oLanguage": {
  "sUrl": "busca/pt-br.txt"
},
        "responsive": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "busca/busca_usuario.php",
         "aoColumnDefs" : [
            {"data": null, "sDefaultContent": "<a href=teste.php?id=' + data[0] + '>teste</a>","aTargets": [5]}
        ]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom quero colocar aqui a solução para que outro usuário com o mesmo problema consiga uma solução.

primeiro em busca_usuario adicionei o id do usuario em id_usuario como podem ver abaixo:

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => '`a`.`id_usuario`',   'dt' => 0, 'field' => 'id_usuario' ),
    array( 'db' => '`a`.`nome`',         'dt' => 1, 'field' => 'nome' ),
    array( 'db' => '`a`.`cpf`',          'dt' => 2, 'field' => 'cpf' ),
    array( 'db' => '`a`.`situacao`',     'dt' => 5, 'field' => 'situacao'),
    array( 'db' => '`b`.`descricao`',    'dt' => 3, 'field' => 'descricao' ),
    array( 'db' => '`c`.`descricao`',    'dt' => 4, 'field' => 'nomegh', 'as' => 'nomegh' )

);
```

Depois na chamada do datatables eu adicionei a coluna com os botões e ocultei a coluna com as IDs pq não me interessa que ela apareça veja abaixo:

```
    $('#jsontable').dataTable({
"oLanguage": {
  "sUrl": "busca/pt-br.txt"
},
        "responsive": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "busca/busca_usuario.php",
  "aoColumnDefs": [    
        {
        "bSearchable": false,
        "bVisible": false,
        "aTargets": [0] // aqui é a coluna do id como é a primeira é 0
        },  
     {
       "aTargets": [ 6 ], // o numero 6 é o nº da coluna
       "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) { //aqui é uma funçãozinha para pegar os ids
         return '<a class="editar fancybox.iframe" href="cadastro_editar.php?id=' + full[0] + '"><img src="imagens/editar.png" width="24px" height="24px" border=0  title="Editar usuário"/></a><a class="ficha fancybox.iframe" href="fichapessoal_editar.php?id=' + full[0] + '"><img src="imagens/atualiza.png" width="24px" height="24px" border=0  title="Editar ficha pessoal"/></a>';
       }
     }
   ]
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado opeta fazia um tempo que estava com esse problema e sua solução me salvou